# adding char as int gives unexpected result

Tags: c, char

I try to do some hex-bin/bin-hex conversion and test which function would be faster but I encountered strange error while adding 'a' as integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* convert bin to hex char [0-9a-f] */
static inline unsigned char ToHex4bits1(unsigned char znak)
//unsigned char ToHex4bits1(unsigned char znak)
    {
    znak &= 0x0F;
    switch(znak)
        {
        case 10: return 'a';
        case 11: return 'b';
        case 12: return 'c';
        case 13: return 'd';
        case 14: return 'e';
        case 15: return 'f';
        default: return znak + 48;  /// 48  0x30    '0'
        }
    }

/* convert bin to hex char [0-9a-f] */    
static inline unsigned char ToHex4bits2(unsigned char znak)
//unsigned char ToHex4bits2(unsigned char znak)
    {
    //unsigned char add = '0';
    int add = '0';  /// [0-9]; add value of '0' (65 0x41    '0')
    znak &=0x0F;
    if(znak > 9)  /// [a-f]; if `znak' <0x0a, 0x0f> /// just one comparison as `znak' cannot be bigger than 15 anyway (znak &=0x0F;)
        {
        add = 0x61;  /// 'a'; // 87 0x61    'a'
        }
    return znak + add;
    }

//-----------//
int main()
    {
    int i;
    //char z;
    int z; 

    printf("\nToHex4bits1(i)\n");
    for(i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
        z = ToHex4bits1(i);
        printf("%d\t%02x\t%c\n", z, z, z);
        }

    printf("\nToHex4bits2(i)\n");
    for(i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
        z = ToHex4bits2(i);
        printf("%d\t%02x\t%c\n", z, z, z);
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

when I run it `$ gcc -o tohex4bits tohex4bits.c; ./tohex4bits` I get this result:

```
ToHex4bits1(i)
48  30  0
49  31  1
(...)
57  39  9
97  61  a
98  62  b
(...)
102 66  f
48  30  0
# which is what I expected

ToHex4bits2(i)
48  30  0
49  31  1
(...)
57  39  9
107 6b  k # that's where things get interesting; it's 10 too much ('k'-'a'==10)
108 6c  l
109 6d  m
110 6e  n
111 6f  o
112 70  p

# which is wrong
```

What is actually wrong with second function `ToHex4bits2()`, why is that adding 'a' (97/0x61) makes it add 'k' (107/0x6b), or 'A' => 'K' for that matter?

Comment: Case 11..15 are easy too: `'a' + znak - 10`. Another approach is to make a simple look-up table: `hex[znak]` and you're done.

Comment: @tadman You mean case 10..15.

Comment: @TomKarzes Precisely.

Comment: return "0123456789abcdef" [znak & 0x0F];

Comment: there are 4 places in the code where there are assignments between 'unsigned' and `int`  Your compiler should have warned you about those problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple. If `znak` is 10, then you want to return `'a'`, but you're returning `'a'+10`. So return `znak+add-10` instead.

But you're making it extremely difficult for yourself. Magic constants all over the place and extremely complicated code for a simple task. This would do:

```
{
znak &= 0x0F;
if(znak > 9) 
    return znak + 'a' - 10;
else
    return znak + '0';
}
```

Or this if you want to be more compact. You're obviously not afraid of complicated code:

```
{
znak &= 0x0F;
return znak > 9 ? znak + 'a' - 10 : znak + '0';
}
```

You mentioned that you're trying to optimize this code. I have a hard time seeing how you could do so much about it. It's likely that you would be better of optimizing a bigger chunk to see if there's something wrong with algorithms or something. But we can do a minor thing about the first, and it's this:

```
#define likely(x)      __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1) 
#define unlikely(x)    __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0) 
static inline unsigned char ToHex4bits1(unsigned char znak)
{
    {
    znak &= 0x0F;
    // Hint the compiler that the first branch is less likely, which
    // improves branch prediction
    if(unlikely(znak > 9)) 
        return znak + 'a' - 10;
    else
        return znak + '0';
    }
}
```

Read about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/branch-prediction-macros-in-gcc/

But I think the fastest method is this:

```
static inline unsigned char ToHex4bits1(unsigned char znak)
{
    const unsigned char ret[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                                  '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    return ret[znak & 0x0F];
}
```

Comment: you meant


    static inline unsigned char ToHex4bits2k(unsigned char znak)
    {
        znak &= 0x0F;
    return znak > 9 ? znak + 'a' - 10 : znak + '0';
    }

Comment: @tansy What's the difference? Have I written anything wrong?

Comment: Well, yes. if `0 < znak < 9` you want to return `'0'-'9'` not `0x00-0x09`.
I guess it's a typo.

Comment: @tansy You're completely right. My mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @tansy Updated with suggestions for optimizations.

Comment: @tansy Please mark the answer you consider best as "accepted". Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I run it 10^9 times and for all these "versions" it took ~10[s]. And you were right about optimization - the difference between all "versions" is less than 0.120[s]. There is no difference really. This code is too short I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Lets take a closer look at the `ToHex4bits2` function:

```
static inline unsigned char ToHex4bits2(unsigned char znak)
//unsigned char ToHex4bits2(unsigned char znak)
    {
    //unsigned char add = '0';
    int add = '0';  /// [0-9]; add value of '0' (65 0x41    '0')
    znak &=0x0F;
    if(znak > 9)  /// [a-f]; if `znak' <0x0a, 0x0f> /// just one comparison as `znak' cannot be bigger than 15 anyway (znak &=0x0F;)
        {
        add = 0x61;  /// 'a'; // 87 0x61    'a'
        }
    return znak + add;
    }
```

If the value of `znak` is larger than `9` then you add the value `0x61` (ASCII code for `'a'`). If `znak` is (for example) `11` (hex `0xb`) the addition results in `0x72` which is the ASCII code for `'r'` To fix this you should subtract `10` (`0xa`) from `znak` first.

And of course you should not use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you mean the character `'a'` then *say* so. In the code itself.

Comment: I added magic numbers in comments so reader knows what I mean by adding and because I was trying to add either way (char/int/hex) I left it somehow. I meant to be `'a'`.